# How to code a simple form using Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Literally picked up RoR today. Just need a few pointers to keep me going. Got really stuck here trying to make a simple form that will do a currency conversion. Only issue is getting the amount in from the form and using it in my code.

```
class IndexController < ApplicationController

def index

end

class Earrningss
    def test(a)
        Money::Bank::GoogleCurrency.ttl_in_seconds = 86400
        Money.default_bank = Money::Bank::GoogleCurrency.new
        amount = a.to_i * 100
        money = Money.new(amount, "USD") # amount is in cents
        comission = money * 0.2
        earnings = money - comission
        result = earnings.exchange_to(:AUD) 
    end
end


def new
    @result = Earrningss.send(params[:a])
    render :index
end end
```

And this is the form:

```
<%= form_for :earrningss, url: { action: :new }, method: :get do |f|   %> 
  <%= number_field_tag :a, params[:a] %>
  <%= f.submit 'Calculate!' %>
<% end %>

<% unless @result.nil? %>
  <p> = <%= @result %> </p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Check the docs, there are just too many things that have to be changed in your implementation. Also checkout https://www.railstutorial.org/

Comment: Try changing `@result = Earrningss.send(params[:a])` to `@result = Earrningss.test(params[:a])`

Comment: @Pavan Thanks! Got this error: private method `test' called for IndexController::Earrningss:Class

Comment: Oh! Instead try changing it to `@result = Earrningss.new` and add this line after that `@result.test(params[:a])`

Comment: @Pavan no error, but it gave me this result `= #<IndexController::Earrningss:0xa8caa28>`

Answer (score 0):

There are fundamental mistakes in your question and understanding of Rails.
It's too broad to specify but let show you some,

```
class Earrningss
```

Should be

```
class Earrning
```

Models are singular.

This is not number_field_tag should've used,

```
 <%= number_field_tag :a, params[:a] %>
```

Replace params[:a] with a variable.

[This](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/) is a complete guide for Rails, please do refer this, it does have an example blog application to get you started.

Good luck.